# How to iterate column values in an object's list?

Tags: java

Here's my code:

```
 public String generateEISReports_PDF(){

    surveyReportService.setSurveyReportDA(surveyReportDA);
    surveyReportList = surveyReportService.getSurveyReport(surveyType, surveyDate, projectCode, employeeCode);
    if(surveyReportList != null){

        System.out.println(surveyReportList + "testing");
        System.out.println(surveyReportList.size() + "size ito");

        for (SurveyReport surveyReport : surveyReportList) {                
            System.out.println(surveyReport.getRiskRank().toString() + "asdf");
            surveyReports.add(surveyReport);
        }

    }

    this.compileTheJasperReports();
    return SUCCESS;
}
```

I am getting the whole row values with this code as an object. I want to iterate the field values in every list of objects. How can I do that?

Comment: I think you're already doing that using the `for` loop in your code.

Comment: i did not understand.Please can u explain

Comment: What I mean is, I want to get the field values for each in every list. I'm not getting it right. What happeens in my code here is that it just iterates all over the list, the whole row values.

Comment: Are u trying to say "I am getting the whole row values with this code as `SurveyReport` object. I want to iterate the field values in `SurveyReport` objects. How can I do that?"

Comment: Yes. You're right. Sorry, I'm not as brilliant as my name suggests. LOL. Please someone help me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

By using reflection you can achieve that. Following is the code. This might help you.

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

public class SurveyReport {  
    public int localServeryCont;  // if you make it private then changes have to be done in 'SurveyIterator' inner class.
    public String surveyReporterName;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<SurveyReport> surveyReportList = new ArrayList<SurveyReport>();
        SurveyReport sr = new SurveyReport(); //first object creation
            sr.localServeryCont = 10;
            sr.surveyReporterName = "AAA";
            surveyReportList.add(sr);

        sr = new SurveyReport();  //second object creation
            sr.localServeryCont  = 100;
            sr.surveyReporterName = "BBB";
            surveyReportList.add(sr);  //two objects are in the list-object.

        for (SurveyReport surveyReport : surveyReportList) {
            Iterator<String> itr = surveyReport.iterator();   //You can work around with 'java.lang.Iterable' to use 'foreach' loop
            while (itr.hasNext()) {  //this is what you might be expecting
                System.out.println("SurveyReport's object's values : " + itr.next());
            }

        }
    }

    public Iterator<String> iterator() { //here is method to get iterator object.
        return new SurveyIterator();
    }

    private class SurveyIterator implements Iterator<String> {  //creating 'SurveyIterator' INNER class
        private int totalAvailableField = SurveyReport.class.getDeclaredFields().length;
        int cursor = 0;
        Field[] surveyReportFields = SurveyReport.class.getFields();

        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            return cursor != totalAvailableField;
        }

        @Override
        public String next() {

            String next = null;
            try {
                next = (surveyReportFields[cursor].get(SurveyReport.this)).toString();
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            cursor++;
            return next;
        }

        @Override
        public void remove() {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
        }
    }
}
```